# Modifying a set of binary files

Tags: binary, escape-characters, special-characters

I have several binary files with the character 0x04 in them, and I'd like to add an escape `\` character before each. Is there a script I can use to do this without needing to manually edit each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GNU sed` as in the following example:

```
for file in /path/*; do
  sed -i 's/\x04/\\&/g' "$file"
done
```

Be aware that `-i` option modify the file in place, so be sure to have a backup, something should go wrong.

Comment: That's works perfectly many thanks Enzo and Michael!!!

Comment: @Luiz You can upvote this and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it solved your problem