# Locate enscript reported non-printable chars

Tags: special-characters, postscript

I'm making a postscript of a bunch of C code, and `enscript` reports I have 2 non-printable chars

```
[ 91 pages * 1 copy ] left in a.ps
2 non-printable characters
non-printable character codes (decimal):
128 153
```

However I couldn't find these chars with `grep`

```
grep -r $'\231' *
grep -r $'\200' *
```

Is there a way to let `enscript` report which lines contain the non-printable chars?

Comment: Maybe this will provide a clue as to how to handle these.  It is not an answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18579/modifying-a-set-of-binary-files

Comment: Found another clue here.  The trick is running the files through hexdump first and searching the output.  Also found some things about using echo with an unescaped $ to pass raw data into grep.  Bottom line, I'm not sure your original grep was correct.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180081/linux-binary-grep  http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/152868-grepping-hex-characters-explanation.html

Answer (score 0):

I manually searched until I found one of the non-printable characters, then used hd to see the hex which revealed e2. The following located all of my non-printable characters:

```
grep $'\xe2' file-with-non-printable-characters
```

I then manually edited to remove them. I don't know why recode UTF-8..ISO-8859-1 would not work and I do not know the significance of character $'\xe2', but grep suited me well. Hopefully, I will get comments so that I can improve this answer.